# Norms and Finite Dimensions

Tags: functional-analysis

In a finite dimensional spaces, is it true that if $\| \|_x > \| \|_y$ if $x > y$?

So for instance is it true that $\| \|_4 < \| \|_6$ since $6 > 4$?

Comment: This is the generalized mean inequality : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take $V = \mathbf{R}^2$ and consider $\mathbf{x} = [2\ 2]^T$, using $x = 4$ and $y = 6$ as in your question.  I assume you mean 
$\|\mathbf{x}\|_p = (\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ if $V = \mathbf{R}^n$.